# Read version.properties file laying in the root folder

Tags: android, filereader

version.properties is laying in root of the folder. I am reading this file from gradle. Now I want to read the same from activity. How can I read this file.

I am getting file no fount exception on following code:

```
File file = new File("/module/version.properties");
FileInputStream fis;
String content = "";
try {
fis = openFileInput(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to read the same from activity. How can I read this file.

You put the file somewhere else, such as `assets/` or `res/raw/`. That file is not packaged in your application.

Or, in Gradle, use those properties with `buildConfigField` to put those properties in `BuildConfig`.